# Finding as many pairs as possible

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to solve a problem but unfortunately my solution is not really the best for this task.

Task:

At a party there are N guests ( 0 < N < 30000 ). All guests tell when they get to the party and when they leave (for example [10;12]). The task is to take photos of as many people as possible at the party. On a photo there can only be 2 people (a pair) and each person can only be on exactly one photo. Of course, a photo can only be taken when the two persons are at the party at the same time. This is the case when their attendance intervals overlap.

My idea: I wrote a program which from the intervals creates a graph of connections. From the graph I search for the person who has the least number of connections. From the connected persons I also select the person who has the least connections. Then these two are chosen as a pair on a photo. Both are removed from the graph. The algorithm runs until no connections are left.

This approach works however there is a 10 secs limit for the program to calculate. With 1000 entries it runs in 2 secs, but even with 4000 it takes a lot of time. Furthermore, when I tried it with 25000 data, the program stops with an out of memory error, so I cannot even store the connections properly.

I think a new approach is needed here, but I couldn't find an other way to make this work.

Can anyone help me to figure out the proper algorithm for this task?

Thank you very much!

Sample Data:

```
10
1 100
2 92
3 83
4 74
5 65
6 55
7 44
8 33
9 22
10 11
```

The first line is the number of guests the further data is the intervals of people at the party.

Comment: Do you need an exact solution or just a good approximation? If you need an approximation only, try heuristic algorithms like simulated annealing, genetic algorithms etc.

Another question: what is the time frame for guests to arrive and leave? Every full hour? Arbitrarily?

Comment: Why not just wait until the first leaving time approaches, then take a photo of the guest about to leave with the one who leaves next among those present? Does taking a photo take time?

Comment: Is it possible to take two photos at the same time?

Comment: @arne.b `one person can only be on one photo`

Comment: @defaultlocale yes, what is the problem? Trivially, add "omitting already photographed guests" at appropriate places. ;-)

Comment: @arne.b simply speaking: when you photograph someone who is still on the party you're leaving other people without a chance to pair with him. And leaving people without a photo may have unpredictable consequences you don't want to deal with ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @defaultlocale Yes, but this someone can pair with only one anyway, and the one leaving needs to be photographed right away, so what is wrong with picking the partner with the fewest pairing possibilities?

Comment: I need the exact number of photos can be taken. Also I need to output the pairs of people who are on the same photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create graph here, this problem can be solved well on intervals structure. Sort people by ascending order of their leaving time(ending point of interval). Then iterate over them in that sorted order: if current person is not intersecting with anyone, then he should be removed. If he is intersecting with more than one person, take as a pair one of them who has earliest leaving time. During iteration you should compare each person only with next ones.

Proving this approach is not so difficult, so I hope you can prove it yourself.
Regarding running time, simple solution will be O(N^2), however I think that it can be reduced to O(N * logN). Anyway, O(N^2) will fit in 10 seconds on a normal PC.

Comment: @stomsteven How is this different from the solution I proposed?

Comment: I don't see how this produces maximality; really would like to see proof of it, because to me it seems the maximum matching problem can be reduced to this, which means you'd have some publishing to do.

Comment: @G.Bach Not every graph is an [interval graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). Are you sure the matching problem is not simpler on this subclass? Also, once the OP says he need the exact number, elsewhere he says he needs an answer within 10 seconds, so I am not sure what his answer the the first comment's question (is an approximation sufficient) would be.

Comment: @arne.b Oh you're right, I didn't think this through properly.

Comment: O(n*logn) can be obtained with segment tree for getting earliest leaving time. So, it's n elements * log(n) per segment tree query.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a classical [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching) problem to me.

You build a graph, where people who can possibly be pictured together (their time intervals intersect) are connected with an edge, and then find maximum matching, for example, with  [Edmond's Blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27s_matching_algorithm).

I wouldn't say, that it's quite easy to implement. However, you can get quite a good approximation of this with [Kuhn's algorithm](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=684427) for maximum matching in **bipartite** graphs. This one is really easy to implement, but won't give you the exact solution.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but I doubt this is it. Edmonds runs in `N^4`, way too much for this problem.

Comment: @IVlad it's `N^3`, and you can always stop the algorithm, use heuristics and other stuff we do :)

Comment: Even `N^2` would be too much for such a large `N`. I doubt stopping this algorithm early and still getting an optimal answer will be good enough.

Comment: @IVlad actually, it would not. `N^2` for 30000 will run for a few seconds on middle-class PC.  

It's important to understand that asymptotic complexity of Edmond's algorithm covers the worst case. If you have a random graph, it's not a worst case so far.

Comment: `N^2` for 30000 will not pass an online judge, which this seems to be from. These are also slow operations, involving pointers, dynamic allocation etc. Online judge PCs are usually slow and they also generally have good worst case tests. I am pretty sure this algorithm wouldn't pass.

Answer (score 1):

I have some really simple idea:

Assume, party will take Xh, make X sets for each hour, add to them appropriate people. Of course, people who will be there longer than hour will be in few sets. Now if there are 2 sets "together" with even number of ppl, you just could take n/2 photos for each sets. If there are 2 sets of odd number of people you are looking for someone who will be on each of that 2 sets, and move him to one of them (so you got 2 even number sets of people who will be on the same time on the party).

Remember to remove all used ppl (consider some `class` - `Man` with lists of all his/her hours).

My idea probably should be expand to more advanced "moving people" algorithm, through more than one neighboring  set.

Comment: But it's not going to be 24h - look at the 92 leaving time for example.

Comment: Ok, I will change 24h to X then... ?

Comment: Still, the starting and the end of the party can be inferred from the first arrival time and the last leaving time respectively. This method could be adapted in a more general case. The real assumption here is that the arrival/departure times are "plenty" hours, which seems legit according to the sample data shown by the OP

Comment: And if X can go up to 10^18, your solution will not be adequate. I don't think the optimal solution relies on this.

Comment: Moreover I think the solution displayed here can lead to "unresolved" cases in which some people leave the party without having been photographed.

Comment: Sure, "The task is to take photos of as many people as possible at the party."

Answer (score 1):

I think the following can do:

First, read all the guests' data and sort them into an array by leaving time ascending. Then, take first element of the array and iterate through next elements until the very first time-match found (next guest's entry time is less than this guest's leave time), if found, remove both from array as a pair, and report it elsewhere. If not, remove the guest as it can't be paired at all. Repeat until the array is empty.

The worst case of this is also N^2, as a party can be like `[1,2],[3,4],...` where no guests could be paired with each other, and the algorithm will search through all 30000 guests in vain all the time. So I don't think this is the optimal algorithm, but it should give an exact answer.

Answer (score 0):

You say you already have a graph structure representation. I assume your vertices represent the guest and the interval of their staying at the party and the edges represent overlap of the respective intervals. What you then have to solve is the graph theoretical [maximum matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_matching), which has been solved before.

However, as indicated in my comments above, I think you can exploit the properties of the problem, especially the transitivity-like "if A leaves before B leaves and B leaves before C arrives, then A and C will not meet, either" like this:

Wait until the next yet unphotographed guest is about to leave, then take a photo of this one with the one who leaves next among those present.

Comment: Well, one of my problems that I cannot create the graph with 25000 data. Even with 4000 it takes 4-7 seconds and I have 10 seconds for all the calculation. 25000 will fail with out of memory error.

Comment: @stomseven We do not know how dense your graph is, so it is hard to tell whether the representation or calculation could be more  efficient. You could also let java use more memory (`-Xss200m -Xmx2000m` or some higher values). Anyway, did you try the second approach? You only need a `class Guest { double comesAt, leavesAt; }` (or `int`s if you want to limit yourself to these) and two lists sorted by the first/second property, respectively, an iteratively increasing time variable and a `currentlyPresent` collection.

Answer (score -1):

You might succeed in thinking about the earliest time a photo can be taken: It is the time when the second person arrives at the party.

So as a photographer, goto the party being the first person and wait. Whenever a person arrives, take a photo with him/her and all other persons at the party. As a person appears only once, you will not have any duplicates.

While taking a photo (i.e. iterating over the list of guests), remove those guests who actually left the party.

Comment: How does your " take a photo with him/her and all other persons at the party" go along with the stipulation that "one person can only be on one photo"?